# Database PK-FK design for future-effective-date entries?

Tags: sql, hibernate, database-design, primary-key

Ultimately I'm going to convert this into a Hibernate/JPA design. But I wanted to start out from purely a database perspective. We have various tables containing data that is future-effective-dated. Take an employee table with the following pseudo-definition:

employee

- id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
- ... data fields ...
- effectiveFrom DATE
- effectiveTo DATE

employee_reviews

- id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
- employee_id INT FK employee.id

Very simplistic. But let's say Employee A has id = 1, effectiveFrom = 1/1/2011, effectiveTo = 1/1/2099. That employee is going to be changing jobs in the future, which would in theory create a new row, id = 2 with effectiveFrom = 7/1/2011, effectiveTo = 1/1/2099, and id = 1's effectiveTo updated to 6/30/2011. But now, my program would have to go through any table that has a FK relationship to employee every night, and update those FK to reference the newly-effective employee entry.

I have seen various postings in both pure SQL and Hibernate forums that I should have a separate employee_versions table, which is where I would have all effective-dated data stored, resulting in the updated pseudo-definition below:

employee

- id INT AUTO_INCREMENT

employee_versions

- id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
- employee_id INT FK employee.id
- ... data fields ...
- effectiveFrom DATE
- effectiveTo DATE

employee_reviews

- id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
- employee_id INT FK employee.id

Then to get any actual data, one would have to actually select from employee_versions with the proper employee_id and date range. This feels rather unnatural to have this secondary "versions" table for each versioned entity.

Anyone have any opinions, suggestions from your own prior work, etc? Like I said, I'm taking this purely from a general SQL design standpoint first before layering in Hibernate on top. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That employee is going to be changing jobs in the future, which would in theory create a new (employee) row

Why? What is the point of this? Your `employee` entity no longer represents an employee, it represents now some abstact concept of "a person in a position".

I believe it would make more sense to separate out the entity that is changing when the employee "changes jobs" - the position - into a separate table, so you do not end up with some messy concept where one physical person is actually multiple `employee` rows.

I don't understand why you think this seems "unnatural" to have to select from the extra table - you would be separating out something that has multiplicity (a person's position) from something that is singular (an employee).

Comment: True. I guess job assignment is a bad property to use in this example. What about, say, their name, address, some property that is truly related to the employee themselves? Say the employee, in a self-service system, wants to update their address to be something new as of a future date? I guess my mind is going to an extreme to where every property is effective-dated, and you end up with my last example where you just have a PK in employees, and all actual data fields are in the employee_versions table.

Comment: You're spot on and saved me from having to type an answer. I don't know why it would seem unnatural that a single entity (an employee) should only appear once in an employee table. That seems perfectly natural to me. I would just add the advice to Scott that he spends a lot of time thinking through the entities in his application from a "real world" perspective to identify them properly. This ability is something that can take even dedicated DB designers years to perfect.

Comment: @Scott - Address is no different than the position. My address is not a part of me. I can have multiple addresses, my address can change. It's a separate entity and should be in a separate table. The possibility of a changing name is more sticky, but depending on your application requirements I can easily see the need for potentially changing data like that in a separate table. It adds a lot of overhead though, so make sure that it's truly required before you try to design around something like that.

Comment: @Scott this depends completely upon the requirements of your system. When employees change their address (for example) is there a need to store all their previous addresses, along with the dates for which that address was "active"? If so then yes, I think you need to "version" this property. You could probably come up with a way to streamline a lot of this, such as storing the startdate/enddate/id in a common table that your other tables then "extend". Generally, the best way to model something is to figure out all the ways in which things can change and model the relationships accordingly

Comment: Completely agree, Tom. We're having a nice debate here in the office about it. Again, an employee's job at a point in time was a bad example, since that can be easily modeled in an employee_jobs dated join table. I meant more in the case of changes to an employee that are to take effect in the future - if that's even to be allowed (again, e.g. name, address, phone, etc changes).

Comment: You shouldn't fear having multiple tables, needing joins, etc - these are the exact tools that make relational databases powerful to model these types of relationships/data

Comment: Oh believe me, I don't. :) Just trying to re-work some of these designs to have a lot more versioned join tables. It just feels funny and odd to have an Employee entity with nothing more than an ID field, and then collections of versions of all the other entities, filtered down to what's current as of a date.

Comment: I like the realization that your database doesn't know anything about the "essence" of the people in your company -- only mutable properties of them!

Answer (score 1):

You need to decide whether you are designing a database to support operations or a data warehouse to support reporting. If it is the second, your design in the beginning is very similar to Kimbal's Type 2 slowly changing dimension. Traditionally, you would want your operational database to represent the most current version of your employee and to provide some business key for it (employee #, SSN, etc.). The data then can be loaded into the data warehouse, where each individual record in the EMPLOYEE dimension would have a surrogate key and effective/end dates. The facts, for example reviews, will be related to the the records in the EMPLOYEE dimension, based on the business key and date/time. For example, you will be able to differentiate reviews of employee A when he was in the Junior Technician position from his reviews when he transitioned to the Senior Engineer position.

Answer (score 0):

For this sort of thing, we usually have a single boolean field called Active, which allows easier querying on the latest record that applies.

Comment: Still, even in that case, you'd have, say, id = 1 active, id = 2 inactive (in waiting). Something would go through and update the active/inactive flags, true. But you'd still end up with other tables with an FK reference to the old id = 1.

Comment: Are you looking for cascading updates?... In any case, would you want an employee_review from a past role associated with the current role?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on [matt b's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431002/database-pk-fk-design-for-future-effective-date-entries/6431131#6431131), your discussion of the problem domain makes it pretty clear that what your design is calling out for is a "position" table. An employee's reviews continue to be relevant to that employee even after they move into a new position. Also, in every corporation I've experienced, the concept of an employee's tenure is related to their entire history at the company, not just the current position.

It's generally good practice to look at any complex updates needed as a sign that the design needs to change.

Answer (score 0):

There is the entity that corresponds to the unique human being:

```
     EMPLOYEE
     eeid PK
     firstname
     surname
     dateofbirth
     dateofhire
     dateoftermination
     etc
```

and there is the entity that corresponds to the position(s) held by the employee:

```
     EMPLOYEEPOSITION
     id pk
     eeid FK references EMPLOYEE(eeid)
     title
     reportsto FK references EMPLOYEE(eeid)
     startdate not null usually
     enddate allows null
```

The question of how to enforce whether an EMPLOYEE's positions can overlap is not typically addressed by creating multiple EMPLOYEE records. Inserts/updates to EMPLOYEEPOSITION typically look at the startdate/enddate columns for each of an EE's positions and, depending on what rule is in effect (e.g. overlaps allowed/disallowed) either commit or rollback the operation.

All of an EE's positions can be found using eeid.

You do not usually put a termination date in the EE record unless and until it's necessary.  If the EE is a contract worker, I'd instantiate the contract term as an EMPLOYEEPOSITION.

You can analogize from here for any entity that exists in a many-to-one relationship back to EMPLOYEE.

Answer (score 0):

Lookup [temporal databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_database).  Your data is temporal, in spite of the fact that the dates may currently be in the future.  Presumably the future oriented data you insert now will still have the same form and meaning when the future change takes effect.