# Does it make sense to have a table that has one column which is an auto-generated column?

Tags: database, database-design

I am designing a database that models the relationship between questions and options for those questions. In part of my database design, I am running into a situation where I find it useful to have a table that has nothing but an auto-generated id column. I find this strange so I thought I would ask here to see if I am thinking of the problem in the right way.

In my database, there are three kinds of questions that I need to account for:

- Free response questions
- Radio button questions
- Drop down questions

Characteristics of application:

1. Radio button questions and drop down questions have an option set in
   which the answer to those questions is constrained to one of the
   options in that option set.
2. It may happen that the same question (of the same type) has a different option set so this is something that my database design
   should be able to handle.
3. It is also likely that different questions have the exact same option set (e.g. {"Yes", "No"}).

Given these characteristics, this is the database design that I came up with:

[image]

As you can see, the table "OptionSet" consists of one column which is just an auto-generated ID column. Is this justified given the characteristics provided? Am I thinking about this design in the proper way?

------------------------------EDIT-----------------------------------

If I removed this OptionSet table, the alternative would be to just have a many to many association table between Question and Option like so:

[image]

The downside to this is that I can imagine that many of the questions will have the same exact options. So if you have the options "yes" and "no" in the option table, every yes or no question would have 2 rows in this association table.

Whereas, with the first database design I showed, there is not as much bloat. The OptionSet with the options "yes" and "no" would be assigned a unique id which could be a foreign key in the Question table.

Comment: Not sure if I stand behind this, but as a way to start thinking about this: could it be that the optionset has properties you didn't list (yet)? For instance, a name to reference it in an interface wouldn't be that strange. Or, more meta, things like creation datetimes or something like that. As soon as those properties of an optionset are on the table, your design could be making more sense?

Comment: This is btw an interesting issue that more people struggled with. Check out these (comments particularly)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6481505/one-column-sql-table-the-column-being-an-id-is-this-crazy
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431002/database-pk-fk-design-for-future-effective-date-entries/6431131

Comment: There isn't really any meta data that would make it have more sense as its entire purpose would be to provide an id that associates with a set of options since the same set of options may be used in several questions. See my edit which may help explain better.

Comment: Not really sure if we are on the same page, I'm suggesting using extra information as a thought experiment to see if the table is 'a thing'. If you can find any of those things, e.g. a name for an interface (which could be the case, as you might want to reference to the options set of "all countries" or "seven colors" or whatever), then the concept is a concept that might deserve a table. Even if you decide not to need the extra information, thinking about the fact that it could theoretically have needed it was the point of the thought experiment.

Comment: ah I see so failure to think of anything could be taken as a sign that it is not deserving of a table.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't quite get the idea that stands behind the OptionSet table. What is its purpose? Also, how do you plan to implement its usage?

If it is auto-generated, it means that database will handle column's values. This is Oracle syntax (I presume you don't use that database, regarding the way you named tables and columns) but never mind that - it is just to illustrate what I'm trying to say:

```
SQL> create table OptionSet
  2    (OptionSetID int generated always as identity);

Table created.

SQL> insert into OptionSet values (1);
insert into OptionSet values (1)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-32795: cannot insert into a generated always identity column
```

OK; so it can't be generated **always**. Switch to another option, so that value is generated only if `null` is provided during insert:

```
SQL> create table OptionSet
  2    (OptionSetID int generated by default on null as identity);

Table created.

SQL> insert into OptionSet (OptionSetID) values (null);

1 row created.
```

Now it works, but - what's the benefit? That column is used as *parent* key for two other tables: `Question` and `OptionSetOption`. You can't insert rows in there unless you **know** which value to use for `OptionSetID` and - if it is auto-generated - you'll have to *return* its value, somehow. In Oracle, you'd use `returning` clause, but it won't work on SQL level but in PL/SQL (procedural extension to SQL) and that *might* become a little bit inconvenient, depending on how you do all the stuff.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL>
SQL> declare
  2    l_OptionSetID int;
  3  begin
  4    insert into OptionSet (OptionSetID) values (null)
  5    returning OptionSetID into l_OptionSetID;
  6    dbms_output.put_line('Inserted value: ' || l_OptionSetID);
  7  end;
  8  /
Inserted value: 3

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Does your database support that? If not, you're in trouble so you'd rather switch to a non-auto-generated column, or (based on my first doubt) get rid of that table entirely as I failed to understand its purpose.

Comment: So if you were to do without that table, there would be a many to many relationship between Question and Option. Many questions will have the same set of options (e.g. {yes, no}). Without the OptionSet table, there would be many rows in the association table between Question and Option pointing to the same options. The idea behind the OptionSet table was to consolidate that such that the Question table gets the option set by the foreign key id.

Comment: I made an edit to my question that compares the design without the OptionSet table which may help provide intuition as to why I think it would be helpful.

Comment: No problem if you think that your approach makes more sense. You asked for our *opinion*, so I shared mine. It doesn't mean that you have to accept it :)

Comment: heh I don't know if it makes more sense. I was only explaining it further since you said you didn't understand its purpose but I realize that there may be holes in my rationale and I may be over-complicating things. Given now that you understand its purpose, do you still think it's silly?